# Class method for square brackets accessor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a way to override square-bracket accessor on a class, i.e.:

```
class Foo {

  constructor() {
    this.bar = {}
  }

  [prop]() {
    return this.bar[prop]
  }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: In particular `get` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get is what I believe you are looking for.

Comment: You can definitely create a getter function, but it will not be able to tell the difference between a `.` property access and a `[ ]` property access in all cases.